# Git - Remove branches not on remote

Tags: git, github

So I'm in a shell and I do the following:

```
git fetch --all --prune
git reset --hard
git branch
```

And the following is listed

```
*master
branch a
branch b
```

On the remote, there are two branches. `master` and `branch a`. I want any branches that aren't on the remote to be gone from my machine. What's the simplest way I can make all extra branches that have been merged to disappear without deleting the local repo and re-downloading it? Is there no individual command for that?

Comment: make sure you select an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete a local branch, call `git branch -d the_local_branch`

Comment: That works for now. I was hoping that perhaps there would be a command that would handle all of the unnecessary ones automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If git tried to implement pushbuttons for every useful thing you could do with a five-line script, it'd take longer to find the right pushbutton than to just write the script.

```
git for-each-ref refs/heads \
    --format='x=`git rev-parse -q --verify "%(upstream)"` \
              || echo git branch -d %(refname:short)' \
| sh -x
```